# XPCOM tab based variable

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, xpcom

When user clicks on of the button in toolbar it opens an url in the browser windows. user can process that content on clicking on some other button on the toolbar.

However it creates a problem when i have multiple tabs opened and each tab contains different url (so when i send a request to the server through toolbar actions it takes id for recently loaded data).

Could you please help me out so i can manage identifier returned from the server for each tab? I am using variable in JS to maintain the identifier for the loaded Url (Url comes from the server with the identifier).

Comment: at last i found the solution which i want to share with you guys!

gBrowser.mCurrentTab.setAttribute(key, value);

Answer (score 1):

gBrowser.mCurrentTab.setAttribute(key, value);